# How can I call the numpy array members which defined in a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to call the array in a function like the one shown below, and I used `from case9 import bus`. However, that results in an import error saying it could not import the name `bus`.

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me determine how to call one of array defined in the function, such as: `gen`, `bus`, `branch`, etc...

```
from numpy import array

def case9():
    ppc = {"version": '2'}

    ##-----  Power Flow Data  -----##
    ## system MVA base
    ppc["baseMVA"] = 100.0

    ## bus data
    # bus_i type Pd Qd Gs Bs area Vm Va baseKV zone Vmax Vmin
    ppc["bus"] = array([
        [1, 3, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [2, 2, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [3, 2, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [4, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [5, 1, 90,  30, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [6, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [7, 1, 100, 35, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [8, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9],
        [9, 1, 125, 50, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 345, 1, 1.1, 0.9]
    ])

    ## generator data
    # bus, Pg, Qg, Qmax, Qmin, Vg, mBase, status, Pmax, Pmin, Pc1, Pc2,
    # Qc1min, Qc1max, Qc2min, Qc2max, ramp_agc, ramp_10, ramp_30, ramp_q, apf
    ppc["gen"] = array([
        [1, 0,   0, 300, -300, 1, 100, 1, 250, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [2, 163, 0, 300, -300, 1, 100, 1, 300, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 85,  0, 300, -300, 1, 100, 1, 270, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ])

    ## branch data
    # fbus, tbus, r, x, b, rateA, rateB, rateC, ratio, angle, status, angmin, angmax
    ppc["branch"] = array([
        [1, 4, 0,      0.0576, 0,     250, 250, 250, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [4, 5, 0.017,  0.092,  0.158, 250, 250, 250, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [5, 6, 0.039,  0.17,   0.358, 150, 150, 150, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [3, 6, 0,      0.0586, 0,     300, 300, 300, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [6, 7, 0.0119, 0.1008, 0.209, 150, 150, 150, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [7, 8, 0.0085, 0.072,  0.149, 250, 250, 250, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [8, 2, 0,      0.0625, 0,     250, 250, 250, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [8, 9, 0.032,  0.161,  0.306, 250, 250, 250, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360],
        [9, 4, 0.01,   0.085,  0.176, 250, 250, 250, 0, 0, 1, -360, 360]
    ])

    ##-----  OPF Data  -----##
    ## area data
    # area refbus
    ppc["areas"] = array([
        [1, 5]
    ])

    ## generator cost data
    # 1 startup shutdown n x1 y1 ... xn yn
    # 2 startup shutdown n c(n-1) ... c0
    ppc["gencost"] = array([
        [2, 1500, 0, 3, 0.11,   5,   150],
        [2, 2000, 0, 3, 0.085,  1.2, 600],
        [2, 3000, 0, 3, 0.1225, 1,   335]
    ])

    return ppc
```

Comment: You can't call arrays. You can't import things that are inside a function.

Comment: Thanks, but can I call that from another created function?

Comment: you cannot _call_ arrays. You can return the whole thing like you're doing now and then get the array like this: `a = yourFunc(); print a["bus"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary is returned by the function. Just assign it to a variable and access it by key:

```
ppc = case9()
bus = ppc['bus']
```